# Extracting two lowest bits and adding to another word

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I've spent the last hour going around in circles on this so it's finally time to ask for help.  I have two binary 8-bit words such as these:

```
$words[0]="00000101";
$words[1]="01111001";
```

I want to take the two right bits (01) of $words[0] and append it to the start of $words[1] to make 0101111001 = 377 in decimal.

The easiest way would be to use PHPs string functions to do a substr() but I'd rather learn how to do it using bitwise operators as I need to do this for lots of other examples as well.

What I thought I'd do is to to do 00000101 AND 0x03 to give me 64 and then shift the bits 8 places to the right so that I can add them to $words[1] using OR.

In code that would be:

```
($array[0] & 0x03 << 8) | $array[1]
```

but I just get the value of $array[1] back.  It seems that it's not possible to shift a value to left more than 8 bits as it gets set to zero (which makes sense).

So, how can accomplish what I want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use binaries. Binaries starts with 0b... without "".
This code works:

```
$words[0]=0b00000101;
$words[1]=0b01111001;

$last = $words[0] & 0b11;
$shift = $last << 8;
$newWord = $shift | $words[1];
echo $newWord;
```

Or in short form:

```
echo ($words[0] & 0b11) << 8 | $words[1];
```

I use the bitwise **& 0b11** to get the last two digits from the first word, shift it with **<<8** and use the bitwise or **|**.
 For the last | you can use + instead, if you want.

**EDIT:**
If you want the result as binary just use decbin:

```
echo decbin($newWord);
```

Comment: Just curious, how will you output `0101111001` rather than `377`?

Comment: complete.. :) +1

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  I was actually using integer representations of my binary strings which is why I got my 0x and 0b muddled up.  All sorted now :-)